# I'm trying to think of a bests practice to "Suppress" an alert (or multiple, but never all alerts) in a table where every row is an alert

Tags: tables, data-tables, alerts

Question says it all.. but I want to be able to select a specific number (or a single) alert (row) and suppress it - AKA don't show it to me again. I also want to be able to see All Suppressed Alerts (with ability to un-suppress) but that is easier, I'd just bring the user to another table for Suppressed Alerts.

My current thinking is to use checkboxes and Closed Eye icons. So I have a 'Suppress' column, and there is a checkbox and a closed eye. The closed eye is deactivated or disabled until there is at least one box checked in the table. Or a user can use the checkbox in the header to suppress all rows in the table, but that would never actually happen.

Each cell in the 'Suppress' column also has a checkbox and a closed eye. So that a user can multi-select, or just suppress one alert by clicking the closed eye.

[image: Image of what I am currently trying (column in question only)]

I just can't help but feel like there is a better way to do this! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need to be able to toggle the 'show suppressed alerts' from this same dialog? It seems that a cleaner, less confusing solution is to have a whole separate menu somewhere else in the UI where users can access the list of suppressed alerts.

Comment: @JonW - that is absolutely my plan! So there will be another tab to view suppressed alerts.

Comment: I guess the confusing thing to me that might help is: what would a better icon be in the header so that they aren’t the exact same as the icons in the rows? Would it make sense to use a different icon at all? It’d be for the same action, just bulk rather than individual suppression.